# How to make `top` only display a group of processes matching a specific pattern?

Tags: bash, debian, shell, process, top

I want to show all processes whose command line includes `.*git.*` using `top`.

I've considered the following command: `top -p $(pgrep -d',' -f '.*git.*')`

However, the above command has several caveats:

- Only processes that exist while `top` is executed will be included in `top`'s output (new `.*git.*`s are not included).
- `man top` says that at most 20 processes may be specified using the `-p` flag, which may not be sufficient.

How can I show a dynamically `top`-like view of current `.*git.*` processes in the terminal?

Comment: Use `htop` instead with `\git`

Comment: Thank you. Is `htop` a successor to `top`? Using `htop \git` still shows e.g. `init` in the output. Why?

Comment: Where do you see in the `man` page that you can enter `\git` on the command line (just curious). I only see `\ ` listed as an interactive command.

Comment: You need to start `htop`, then type `\git` (or F4 followed by `git`).

Comment: @Shuzheng I didn't say it was a command line option. Are you specifically looking for command line options only?

Comment: @muru - no it's fine :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do this in `top` using “filtering in a window”: start `top`, then press <kbd>O</kbd>, and enter

```
COMMAND=git
```

This will filter processes, matching the `COMMAND` column and keeping only processes whose visible value in that column contains `git`.

When filtering on the `COMMAND` column, the filter applies to the currently-displayed value — either the name of the running program, or its full command line. This can be toggled by pressing <kbd>c</kbd>, or with the `-c` argument; the state is remembered between `top` invocations. Note that the filter applies only to the visible portion of the field; this can be a significant gotcha when filtering on the `COMMAND` column, if it isn’t fully visible or if it isn’t wide enough to include the relevant part of the command line. See the `COMMAND` field description in [`man top`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/top.1.html#3._FIELDS_/_Columns) for details.

Filters are cumulative and can be cleared by pressing <kbd>=</kbd>. See section 5e of [`man top`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/top.1.html#5._ALTERNATE-DISPLAY_Provisions) for details.

As far as I’m aware there’s no equivalent command-line option.